# I am using spring security 3.2.7 with tomcat 6 and I weed to make logout button

Tags: spring-security, tomcat6

I am using angularjs with spring security 3.2.7 and deploy on tomcat 6  used this code for login operation

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, ? extends Object> login(
                        HttpServletRequest request,
                        @RequestParam String userName,
                        @RequestParam String password) {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    logger.info("RegistreController Login...");
    logger.info("Start Login for the user :"+userName);
    try{
    String encodedPassword = hashPassword(password);
    System.out.println("encodedPassword = "+encodedPassword);

    final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, encodedPassword);

    // this function returns UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities)
    final Authentication authentication = authenticationProvider.authenticate(authRequest);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    CustomUser user = null;
    if (principal instanceof CustomUser) {
        user = ((CustomUser)principal);
    }
}catch(Exception e) {
     if(e instanceof CredentialsExpiredException){
         response.put("expired", true);
     }
     response.put("success", false);
     response.put("msg", e.getMessage());
     logger.fatal(new MasterProtectionLogger().reportError("UserAdminController.login()", e, logger));
}
  return response;
}
```

I need to write logout by code (not calling j_spring_security_logout)
how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The key line is:

```java
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

You may also want to invalidate the HTTP session.